# Any dangers for the usage of sacramentals that are not-yet-blessed-by-a-priest?

Tags: catholicism, rosary

I just bought a new Rosary, and I haven't asked our priest in the locality to bless it.

Is there any danger when I pray the Rosary (or use of any "not-yet-blessed" sacramental for this matter) using this one?

Thanks for answering! =)

Comment: I don't know the official Catholic stand on this, as I'm not Catholic, but I have to wonder:  What would the danger possibly be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a priest would tell you that the danger is in not praying it, they're usually pragmatic like that.

Like some sacraments (Confession, Baptism) the intent is perhaps as important the action

> For catechumens who die before their Baptism, their explicit desire to receive it, together with repentance for their sins, and charity, assures them the salvation that they were not able to receive through the sacrament.

[CCC 1259](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p2s2c1a1.htm)

Always remember that God exists outside of time and your prayers, in communion with the Saints are holy. Also, consider the fact that you could pray the Rosary nearly as easily without the aid of a rosary by counting your fingers and toes.

Comment: So, either blessed or not-blessed is irrelevant, as long as I am praying with all the intent? =)

Comment: I mean ought to have the intent to get it blessed.  Usually it's easy to get rosaries blessed, just ask a priest after mass. If you put it off for too long you probably no longer have the intent. In any event the prayer is the main thing! There's nothing inherently dangerous about unblessed items. The two dangers are scrupulosity (being too worried about those things) and superstition (putting your faith in things which are not God).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any danger of a non-blessed rosary except for omission of prayer just because I don't have a blessed rosary. It's also completely OK to pray the prayer of rosary without a rosary as the item. The item is not really important, the prayer is important.

On the other hand, the intent of the blessing is to help my prayer, so it's not useless. You can translate the blessing as a prayer for the wielder of the rosary to pray well. This is not just the priest's personal prayer, it has the authority of the Church. The effect is similar to someone praying with you (probably not as important, but it stacks) - and every Christian know that it's completely OK to pray alone, but prayer of two or three is better.